# Docker-compose and PHP composer not found although it says the opposite

Tags: docker, docker-compose, composer-php

I'm quite new to Docker. I have a Laravel project I did using Laragon. I would like to create a Docker Compose project out of it. My problem is, when I install composer, even if the terminal is showing me no error, I can't see anything inside of the container.

What I have:

- I have a docker-compose.yml with PHP and NGINX services
- I have a Dockerfile for the laravel app

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.3.19-fpm-stretch

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    gnupg \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    libzip-dev \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl


# Microsoft SQL Server Prerequisites
RUN apt-get update \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list \
        > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        locales \
        apt-transport-https \
    && echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
        unixodbc-dev \
        msodbcsql17

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

RUN pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv xdebug

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | \
    php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Run composer install
RUN composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

RUN composer dump-autoload --optimize

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and 
EXPOSE 9000

# Start php-fpm server
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

What I get when I run `docker-compose build`:

```
    [...]
Step 11/21 : RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer |     php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer
 ---> Running in 9ee162ed2895
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

Composer (version 1.10.8) successfully installed to: /usr/bin/composer
Use it: php /usr/bin/composer

Removing intermediate container 9ee162ed2895
 ---> dc1df86b9a7b
Step 12/21 : COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/
 ---> 7bcf92a0a647
Step 13/21 : RUN composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader
 ---> Running in f1695442d1db
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 113 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing doctrine/inflector (2.0.3): Downloading (100%)
    [...] (all composer packages seem to be installed correctly)

Step 17/21 : RUN composer dump-autoload --optimize
 ---> Running in 18b8c992ace9
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: facade/ignition
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: fruitcake/laravel-cors
Discovered Package: laravel/socialite
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Discovered Package: socialiteproviders/manager
Package manifest generated successfully.
Generated optimized autoload files containing 4925 classes
Removing intermediate container 18b8c992ace9
 ---> d5075486971d
Step 18/21 : COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www
 ---> 15fcdde49457
Step 19/21 : USER www
 ---> Running in be9ab541543c
Removing intermediate container be9ab541543c
 ---> e17d1ae7a052
Step 20/21 : EXPOSE 9000
 ---> Running in 3e09f6279930
Removing intermediate container 3e09f6279930
 ---> 7a3649b9df62
Step 21/21 : CMD ["php-fpm"]
 ---> Running in 0db51df5de3c
Removing intermediate container 0db51df5de3c
 ---> fbb8e77bb8d1
Successfully built fbb8e77bb8d1
Successfully tagged digitalocean.com/php:latest
```

The docker-compose build sounds like it's working.
When I run `docker-composer up -d` and I go to http://localhost, I have a PHP error :

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/www/public/index.php on line 24
```

What I did so far:

- Delete all the containers/images, rebuild
- Edit the Dockerfile according to some tutorials I found on the internet
- Verified that there's a vendor directory in www. Result : no.
- Tried to execute `composer install` directly into the container (within `docker exec -it <container-name> /bin/sh`) : Result : `/bin/sh: composer: not found`.

I can't see where I'm wrong, and I don't understand where exactly does composer had installed its packages, and how to run my project...

Thanks forehand.

Comment: `COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www` looks suspicious to me - does this override the former stuff? Additionally, this does not look related to Composer itself to me

Comment: Deleted existing images and build it again without this line and it's exactly the same.
I just noticed that, I edited my question. Thank you @NicoHaase.

Comment: "Exactly the same" - maybe you install the dependencies and remove them directly afterwards by calling that `COPY` command. Have you tried to chekc that?

Comment: I think this is it. I had to COPY first and then RUN composer install. It makes sense, actually. I can now use my Laravel app. Thank you @NicoHaase !